# max and min values in MS Excel within a range of postive and negative values

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a range of negative to positive values in a column and need to find min and max value and show the min. value (if there is a negative value then it should show negative sign along with value eg. -123) and max value.   I have used MIN, MAX; AGGREGATE Min and Max formulas, however the excel is throwing either #Num! or zero.

List of values
0.6828 
10.3380
16.6222
76.0000
-152.0000
NULL
82.7778
128.0000
-130.3333
-791.0000
159.2000
13.1695
14.1091
48.4375
37.4762
19.2439

Expected output
Min = -791
Max = 159.200

Unable to get values with "Aggregate" function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then your numbers are probably stored as text and not true numbers.

Comment: In this case use formula `value` formula to convert to num

Comment: Yes I edited, I think that it is better to create a full column with values converted and then apply the Max and Min on this column

Comment: @RupeshNash it is also recommand to use `=value(trim(clean()))` to be sure to remove space or invisible character

Comment: I have tried "Value" formula with Aggregate, it is showing #Value! error.  Any suggestions please.  Thanks

Comment: =AGGREGATE(5,7,VALUE(I3:I182)) - this is the formula I have used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220757/discussion-between-rupesh-nath-and-maxigui).